# Aurelia validatejs not working when bind on a object

Tags: validation, aurelia

I was playing around with aurelia-validatejs and was able to validate simple fields on a page. On the same page, I tried initializing a object and bind validation to that object and it stops working:

```
user_data:IUserData = {
    Login:"",
    Id         : null,
    UserProfile: {
        UserId: null
    },
    Permissions: null
};
constructor(){
    this.reporter = ValidationEngine.getValidationReporter(this.user_data);

    // if I just use this and not user_data object,
    // it works and error message is displayed in UI

    this.validator = new Validator(this.user_data)
        // when I use this.user_data (user_data object), it does validate 
        // and I can see validation result on console, but it's not shown in UI

        .ensure('Login').required().length({minimum: 3, maximum:10});
        this.observer = this.reporter.subscribe(result => {
            console.info(result);
        });
}
```

Someone [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892564/1267177) that validatejs looks for a label, and I do have it, it worked when I initialize on `this` object but as soon as I want to validate on `this.user_data` property, it just doesn't display in UI, but I can see it on console.

```
<form action="" submit.delegate="createUser()">
    <div class="input-group ${user_data.Login | loginClass}">
        <label></label>
        <input placeholder="Login" type="text" class="form-control"
            keyup.delegate="validate()"  value.bind="user_data.Login & validate">
    </div>
</form>
```

This doesn't work, but if I clear `user_data` like:

```
    user_data:IUserData = {
        Login:"",
        Id         : null,
        UserProfile: {
            UserId: null
        },
        Permissions: null
    };
constructor(){
        this.reporter = ValidationEngine.getValidationReporter(this);

        //if I just use this and not user_data object,
        //it works and error message is displayed in UI

        this.validator = new Validator(this)
            .ensure('Login').required().length({minimum: 3, maximum:10});
        this.observer = this.reporter.subscribe(result => {
            console.info(result);
        });
}
```

and

```
<form action="" submit.delegate="createUser()">
    <div class="input-group ${user_data.Login | loginClass}">
        <label></label>
        <input placeholder="Login" type="text" class="form-control"
            keyup.delegate="validate()"  value.bind="Login & validate">
    </div>
</form>
```

This works and is displayed in UI. I searched a little bit on Stack Overflow and got few results: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844923/aurelia-validation-working-but-not-displaying-validation-messages). (My problem is similar. I have error messages on UI if I don't use it on a object but when I try to use it on an object, it logs on console but it doesn't display in UI.)

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180765/aurelia-validation-validation-error-detected-but-no-error-message) but it wasn't of much help.

I found [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934767/aurelia-validation-no-message-shown-on-failed-validation) which wasn't of much help either.

Comment: You should probably close this one and post a link to your issue

Comment: Yes true, will do it right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I dug around a little bit and asked developers in Gitter. As it turns out, it's a bug in validatejs plugin.

Recent changes were made to make something available on all classes, and when that change was done, validatejs looks for validationError Reporter on same model even if we provide different model.

A small hacky workaround is to have

```
this.__validationReporter__ = ValidationEngine
    .getValidationReporter(this.user_data);
```

Instead of:

```
this.reporter = ValidationEngine.getValidationReporter(this.user_data);
```

I have reported this [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/validatejs/issues/77) and will update once they come up with something.

For now I'm gonna use

```
this.__validationReporter__ = ValidationEngine
    .getValidationReporter(this.user_data);
```

Or one other workaround is to downgrade to 0.3.x which is not very recommended as there might have been some important changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `form-group`?  Usually our validation problems come down to HTML structure not conforming to the library.

```
<form action="" submit.delegate="createUser()">
    <div class="form-group ${user_data.Login | loginClass}">
        <label></label>
        <input placeholder="Login" type="text" class="form-control"
            keyup.delegate="validate()"  value.bind="Login & validate">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I have used `form-group` I even tried `input-group` inside a `form-group`, `form-group` alone, it just doesn't work. When I don't want to use the object user_data, it magically works